# Recovering Steam cloud saves

Tags: steam, the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I was playing Binding of Isaac: Rebirth on a laptop which I hadn't used to play BoI before. I still had access to my saves because of the cloud. Then the battery died and everything crashed.

When I logged back in, I was prompted to choose between my local and cloud saves. I chose the local saves, as they were newer so I assumed they'd include my current run. I was wrong- this uploaded a blank save, erasing all my progress.

My old save data still exists on my main PC and I want to make sure I keep them. How do I make sure I have the option to do that next time I use my main PC?

Answer (score 4):

Judging by the question date is quite likely you already resolved this. But I'll answer for future generations.

If you start steam on the PC it will overwrite the local save. So you have to:

1. Back up the save file.
2. Let steam overwrite it.
3. Start the game.
4. Alt-Tab the game and replace the current save with the backup.
5. Close the game.

Steam will update the cloud save file with your backup then.

Answer (score 0):

You can sync your steam achievements with your local save by pressing Alt+F2 on the stats screen. This will give you all of your unlocked items, characters, and misc achievements. If you had an in-progress run, that run will be lost.